# Normal closure of finite extension

Tags: field-theory

Let $[E : F]$ be a finite extension, and let $N$ be the normal closure of $E$ over $F$. Let $\alpha \in E$ which does not belong to $F$. Then $N$ is a normal extension of $F(\alpha)$. But is it true, that $N$ is also a normal closure of $E$ over $F(\alpha)$?

I ask this question, because this is asserted in a step of the proof of ***Theorem 15.4*** in the book ***Field Theory*** by ***Ian Adamson*** (Available here https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToFieldTheory/page/n53/mode/2up)

Answer (score 1):

What do you get with $F=\Bbb{Q},E=\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/4}), \alpha= 2^{1/2}$

Comment: Thanks. I'm not quite sure if I'm correct when I say that $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/4},i)$ is a normal closure of $E$ over $F$, and $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/4})$ is a normal closure of $E$ over $F(\alpha)$. But then this would be a counterexample. (The proof of Theorem 15.2 in the book contains a recipe for constructing a normal closure)